# searchable grid using knockout in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

I need solution for my problem on urgent basis, I am new with mvc, knockout please provide me sample code for my problem. any help will be highly appreciated.

suppose I have an observable array in my viewmodel i.e

```
var viewmodel = {
  vendorproviders : ko.observablearray([])
}
```

where vendorproviders list consist of multiple attributes like id, name, country, address etc

I want to populate that array in my grid where each row will have a select button, when that button is clicked it should post the id to my controller action either by submitting or by ajax call.

Furthor more that grid should be searchable like if there is a separate text box, based on the value of text box grid should display matching providers else display all providers.

when user search for particular provider grid should populate from observable array instead of making call at server again and again to pupulate the observable array.

Comment: What's the specific question?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting here.
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro
What you are talking about is all the basic functionality of the tools you referenced.